# how to compare two textboxes with different values in Kendo grid pop up

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<CRMVehicleViewModel>()
                                    .Name("CompanyGrid")
                                    .Columns(columns =>
                                    {
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.VehicleId).Hidden(true);
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.RegNo);
                                        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.FranchiseCode, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["FranchiseCode"], "Value", "Text").EditorTemplateName("GridForeignKey").Title("Franchise Code").Width(150);
                                        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.Model, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["ModelCode"], "Value", "Text").EditorTemplateName("GridForeignKey").Title("Model Code").Width(150);
                                        columns.ForeignKey(p => p.Variant, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["VariantCode"], "Value", "Text").EditorTemplateName("GridForeignKey").Title("Variant Code").Width(150);
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.EngNo);
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.chessisno);
                                        columns.Bound(p => p.Description);  

                                        columns.Command(command => { command.Destroy().Text(" ");command.Create().Text(" ") }).Title("Action").Width(100);
                                    })
                                     .ToolBar(toolbar =>
                                     {
                                         { toolbar.Create(); }
                                     })
                                     .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
                                     .Pageable(p => p.Numeric(false).PreviousNext(false))
                                     .Sortable()
                                     .Scrollable(sc => sc.Endless(true))
                                     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:90%;" })
                                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                        .Ajax()
                                        .ServerOperation(false)
                                       .PageSize(20)
                                       .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.VehicleId))
                                       .Read(read => read.Action("GetVehicles", "CRM"))
                                       .Create(create => create.Action("AddVehicles", "CRM"))
                                       .Destroy(update => update.Action("DeleteVehicles", "CRM"))
                                    ).Events(e => e.Edit("onEdit")))

<script>
    function onEdit(e) {
        var _txt1 = e.container.find("input:EngNo").val();
        var _txt2 = e.container.find("input:chessisno").val();

        if (_txt1 == _txt2) {
            alert('Matching!');
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert('Not matching!');
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

I want to campare Textbox 'EngNo' and textbox 'ChessisNo', both fields must be different before insertion from popup window, I added script already, but it's not working, please help me solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
    function onEdit(e) {
var _txt1 = e.container.find("input[name='EngNo']").val() ;       
var _txt2 = e.container.find("input[name='chessisno']").val();
        if (_txt1 == _txt2) {
            alert('Matching!');
            return true;
        }
        else {
            alert('Not matching!');
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```